# File copy notification to email

Tags: shell

Is there any bash script to notify if some user copying the data from one folder to another?
and getting email notification for the same.

I have searched the same for this on many sites but didn't get the proper solution.

Comment: Please add some more detail. How user is going to copy the files from one directory to another (terminal or GUI)? Which copying utility or command a user will use `cp` or `rsync` etc?

Comment: This is not in the scope of `bash`. You also did not specify what platform you are using. Perhaps [inotify](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) is something you can use?

Comment: am using centos 7.